# HTML5 database: SQL error on DELETE LIMIT

Tags: sql, database, html, limit

I'm trying HTML5 database and found that DELETE is not working with LIMIT.

Trying in Chrome:

```
> select * from my_table limit 1
item  name
--------------
1     Hi

> delete from my_table limit 1
near "limit": syntax error
```

Is there any wrong with this delete?

Thanks.

Comment: Just found that following can delete one of the records that matches some criteria:

`delete from my_table where rowid in (select rowid from my_table where item=1 limit 1 )`

Comment: Btw, if SQLite is compiled with the SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT compile-time option, then DELETE will support LIMIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that `delete` supports `limit` (or, at least it doesn't in any SQL dialect that I'm aware of).  Instead, you'll either want to delete everything from the table via

```
delete from my_table;
```

or be more specific about the rows that you want to delete:

```
delete from my_table where item=1;
```

***Edited to add:*** In general, databases don't tend to care about the order of the rows unless you tell it to (either via an `order by` statement or a `row_number()` function that is present in some RDBMSs).  So, in general, if you call `select * from my_table limit 1;` several times, you aren't guaranteed to get the same row each time.  In other words, unless you really just want a specific number of rows from a table and you don't care which rows you get, a `limit` statement is rarely helpful without imposing some order on the rows fetched by your query.

Comment: MySQL allows for a LIMIT clause on a DELETE and SQL Server allows for TOP (which is the same thing) but both are non-standard SQL extensions.

Comment: @Jeff Mc:  Gotcha.  My SQL experience is prettymuch entirely in PostgreSQL, where `limit` isn't allowed in a `delete` (at least, not on the version in which I'm running).  It would seem kind of dangerous to do that, though, since it would leave open the possibility of deleting a (somewhat) random row...

Comment: Correct, LIMIT will delete a "random" selection of rows.  The only time I use it is when I'm deleting a very large number of rows and keep rerunning it until the number of rows modified is 0 (the whole set matching the predicate is deleted.)  This can help reduce locking and transaction log overflow with very large deletes.

Comment: Thanks. I was checking a wrong reference for DELETE.. The collect one(SQLite which HTML5 database follows) should be here: [DELETE](http://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)

Answer (score 2):

For SQL dialects that allow for a LIMIT on SELECT but not DELETE, try `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE item IN (SELECT item FROM my_table LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Thanks. Actually what I what is to "delete one of the records that matches", it is possible that there are many duplicate records in the table. Tried your way but it will still delete all records that matches.

Comment: Oops, I was making the false assumption that `item` was a unique key.